# Magento how to add a required field to the shipping method?

Tags: php, magento-1.7, checkout

I have added a dropdown box in the template file of my shipping method. Now I want to make it a required field. I have tried so many ways. But didn't worked. Any help will be appreciated.

Below is the template file.

```
<?php 
    $_code=$this->getMethodCode();
    $carrier = $this->getMethodInstance();
    $pickupData = $this->getQuote()->getPickupData();
    $_rate = $this->getRate();
    if(!isset($pickupData['store']))
    {
        $pickupData['store'] = -1;
    }
    if(!isset($pickupData['name']))
    {
        $pickupData['name'] = '';
    }
?>
<ul class="form-list" id="shipping_form_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" style="display:none;">
    <li>
        <label for="shipping_pickup[store]" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Choose Store Location:') ?></label>
        <span class="input-box" style="float:left ;">
            <select class="required-entry" name="shipping_pickup[store]" id="shipping_pickup[store]">
                <option value='0'><?php echo $this->__('Select Store..');?></option>
                <?php 
                    $collection = $this->getAllLocations();
                    foreach($collection as $coll)
                    {
                        $data = $coll->getData();
                        ?>
                        <option value='<?php echo $data['location_id']; ?>'><?php echo $this->__($data['location_name']);?></option>
                        <?php 
                    }
                    ?>
            </select>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In opcheckout.js edit the line 663 to 763.

```
 validate: function() {
        var methods = document.getElementsByName('shipping_method');

        if (methods.length==0) {
            alert(Translator.translate('Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no shipping methods available for it. Please make necessary changes in your shipping address.').stripTags());
            return false;
        }

        if(!this.validator.validate()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (var i=0; i<methods.length; i++) {
            if (methods[i].checked) {

                var methodName = methods[i].value;
                if(methodName == 'pickup_pickup')
                    {
                var locationOpt = document.getElementById('shipping_pickup[store]');
                var selectedOpt = locationOpt.options[locationOpt.selectedIndex].text;

                if(selectedOpt == 'Select Store..')
                    {
                        alert(Translator.translate('Please specify a location.').stripTags());
                        return false;

                    }
                else
                    {
                    return true;
                    }
                    }
                else
                    {
                return true;
                    }
            }
        }
        alert(Translator.translate('Please specify shipping method.').stripTags());
        return false;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is always going to work because it is always going be set in the $_POST array which seems to turn into an array called $pickupData

You will need to alter your code to make sure that $pickupData['store'] is not a zero

```
//make sure this variable is available in the array to avoid errors
//check to make sure variable is not a zero still
if(isset($pickupData['store']) && $pickupData['store'] == 0){
    $pickupData['store'] = -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is not working.I want to show an javascript alert when user doesn't selected an store and click on the checkout button. Same as when the user hasn't selected a shipping method and tries to checkout.